# Binding x:Load, updating bound value doesn't load the control (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a grid element with the `x:Load` attribute bound to a variable in the page:

## Page.xaml

```
<Page>
...
    <Grid x:Name="grd" x:Load="{x:Bind LoadGrid, Mode=OneWay}">
```

## Page.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class Page : Page
...
bool LoadGrid;
```

After receiving the passed argument from the `OnNavigatedTo` event handler, I set the value of `LoadGrid` accordingly:

```
request = (Request) e.Parameter;

if (request == null)
    LoadGrid = false;
else {
    LoadGrid = true;
    InitializeComponent(); // Tried adding this to refresh the controls.
    grd.Loaded += grd_Loaded;
}
```

When the line `grd.Loaded += grd_Loaded;` is executed, an ArgumentException is thrown:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred ...
Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.
```

I check and the value of `grd` is `null` even though the `x:Load` property is true and the binding mode is OneWay (the control "checks" for updates in the bound value).

## Edits

**ATTEMPT 1**

Calling `this.InitializeComponent()` to re-init the controls.

**ATTEMPT 2** [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52460989/2406269) by @touseefbsb:

Use the MVVM approach to create an event for updating the property value.

**ATTEMPT 3**

Tried `.FindName("grd")` after setting the load value, didn't work.

Comment: Is the Grid the root element in the page? If so, you can't use x:Load there. It has to be one level deeper.

Comment: No, it is inside another grid.

Comment: Doesn't x:Bind only trigger once ever? I'm usually in WPF, which doesn't have this binding, but I think I remember reading about it at some point.

Comment: @BradleyUffner This is correct, `{x:Bind}` defaults to `OneTime`, while `{Binding}` which is used with WPF defaults to `OneWay`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unlike in prior XAML platforms, the [OnNavigated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto#remarks) method is called before the visual tree is loaded.

So, you could register the Grid's loaded event in the Page's loaded event handler like the following:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    var request = e.Parameter;

    if (request == null)
        LoadGrid = false;
    else
    {
        LoadGrid = true;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += BlankPage1_Loaded;
    }
 }

private void BlankPage1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    grd.Loaded += Grd_Loaded;
}

private void Grd_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Grd loaded.");
}
```

Comment: After a dispatcher executes code on the UI thread (and by that point I know that all of the UI has loaded), when the dispatcher finishes, an `ArgumentNullException` is thrown. Is that out of the scope of this question?

Comment: @Phantom If you have new questions, please post a new thread. If my reply has resolved your question on current thread, please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later, Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

the **OneWay** binding also required the property to use **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface.

First of all your **LoadGrid** should be a property and not just a field like following

```
public bool LoadGrid {get; set;}
```

after that you need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged which is best to be used with a ViewModel ( MVVM pattren )

make a **ViewModel** class with the implementation.

```
public class PageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool loadGrid;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };


    public bool LoadGrid
    {
        get { return this.loadGrid; }
        set
        {
            this.loadGrid = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        // Raise the PropertyChanged event, passing the name of the property whose value has changed.
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

after that make a property which is of type **PageViewModel** within your page like :

public PageViewModel vm {get; set;} = new PageViewModel();

then within your OnNavigatedTo() method you can set the property like you want. and you dont need to call InitializeComponent again to refresh anything.

```
if (request == null)
    vm.LoadGrid = false;
else {
    vm.LoadGrid = true;
    grd.Loaded += grd_Loaded;
}
```

the last change you need to make is a little change in xaml just bind to vm.LoadGrid instead of LoadGrid like following :

```
<Grid x:Name="grd" x:Load="{x:Bind vm.LoadGrid, Mode=OneWay}">
```

> more details on data binding in depth : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth

Comment: Should I write any code inside the `= delegate { }`? (Never did MVVM before...)

Comment: you do not need to write anything inside delegate {}

Comment: are you still getting the same exception? also have you tried attaching the loaded event in the xaml instead of in code behind?

Comment: Tried moving the binding to the XAML side, the exception I'm now getting is essentially the same, `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.` but now it's from `App.g.i.cs` (might be something native but I have issues with VS regarding mixed debugging).

Comment: Tracking the ViewModel, seems like everything is okay there - the property is updated and the delegate is called upon the change.

Comment: ahan maybe it is not possible to do this with binding because I myself have never tried attaching a property to x:Load attribute, what is you scenario? maybe you can find an alternate way to do this like visibility?

Comment: or just creating and then adding the grid dynamically from backend, and remove the xaml of the grid completelly?

Comment: Up until now, I used visibility but the XAML could take up to 8 seconds to load, so sadly this isn't possible in this scenario. Creating the grid from the back-end would be quite complex (do you mean doing this Object Oriented style, i.e. creating a grid object and assigning children?) since the grid is hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: you can load the grid , set its visibility to visible from the start, and just keep its opacity to 0, and then when u want it u can set its opacity to 1 again.

Comment: But the loading itself takes a lot of time. Before I applied the `x:Load` attribute the loading time would be between 1000 and 8500 ms, now the loading takes 200 ms at most. The issue is about binding the event...

Comment: I dont know what hve you put in that grid that it is taking so long, but if the binding doesnt work maybe you need to remove binding and set x:Load attribute directly on the xaml, but then you need to figure out how to change it from code behind.

Comment: Sadly the property `.Load` does not exist in the code, only as an attribute.